# constantly changing (hibernate) data model, how to avoid server shutdown

Tags: sql, hibernate, tomcat

I am building a webapplication that uses hibernate and mysql and tomcat.  Am constantly being asked for new features as the product evolves, and this often means that the data model needs to be changed.

What I am doing now is exporting all the critical data of the database to a flat file.  Shutting down the database and the server, reconfiguring the database to match the new hibernate mappings and mysql tables and columns, importing the saved data programatically to fit the new data model, and then restarting the servers.

What else is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in zero down time deployments then there are lots of ways to approach this. I found [this](http://watchitlater.com/blog/2011/08/zero-downtime-deployments/) blog post that outlines different strategies to achieve this.

The basic gist is that you do the database upgrade at a separate time to the main applications and ensure that the database has nullable columns and that the code can adjust to having columns mysteriously appear or disappear.

The author gives some strategies for doing this for different technologies - but then admits that it's a bit fiddly to do this with hibernate:

> Hibernate – can be a bit of a bugger in getting it to behave,
>   especially if columns are removed. You usually wind up creating common
>   interfaces for persistent classes, with multiple versions of
>   implementing classes. You can decide which set of classes to wire into
>   Hibernate by using schema or result set metadata before initialising
>   the SessionFactory. Worse issues exist for other persistence
>   technologies in Java, especially the many flavours of JPA that like to
>   instrument the bytecode of classes at startup.

It's a great and interesting article and I recommend reading it all.

(Facebook and Yahoo don't use Hibernate!)

To give the appearance of zero downtime from a users perspective, then it generally involves the use of application clusters protected by load balancers - so you can take each app out of policy and upgrade it without users trying to access it while it is restarting. You have to consider session stickyness, datasource consistency and all sorts of other stuff - but the main thing is that it isn't magic.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing else recommended. If this way of doing works for you, it's fine. You could also use alter statements to make your database schema evolve. Use temporary tables to migrate your data, etc. if exporting and importing to/from a flat file isn't possible anymore due to the large volume of data. But at some time, data must be migrated in a way or another.

Comment: I'm wondering how yahoo and facebook change their database models drastically without outages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dbdeploy](http://code.google.com/p/dbdeploy/wiki/GettingStarted) or a similar incremental database tool to allow you to just add the deltas betweeen upgrades.

They keep track of the version of the database for you and as you develop you add a new Delta for each model change you make. When you upgrade the production server you run dbdeploy against it and determine what state the database is  in and then only applies the necessary upgrades.

This means you never have to export and reimport your data - you just apply the updates to the existing data model - this would drastically speed up your deployment time but there will still be a little outage.

It's recommended that you take dumps of the database before upgrade - because then you can rapidly rollback if things go bad.

**EDIT**

I found this [link](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/zero-downtime-deploys-with-migrations/) on how EngineYard achieve zero downtime using migrations - they use Ruby but there approach is similar to what I outlined here.